# How To create a list of String inside a list in SQLite database in andoid studio?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a Class of User that has name,id,email and other attributes, and i am making a movie app.The users for this app are saved inside a database (SQLite databse) and i want to add the movies that this person rated to the same database by adding the Title of each movie to a list and adding the rating to another list in the Users database.
so the database would look something like:
Users

```
Email         Name   Password        (List<String>) RatedMovies      (List<Float>)Ratings
u1@test.com   user1   asd32r2sa!@3    ["firstMovie","secondMovie"]     [2.5,5.0]
u2@test.com   user2   asdasd12%#s1    ["MovieTest"]                    [9.5]
u3@test.com   user    dfg234DS@#sad   ["Testing","firstMovie"]         [7.0,2.0]
```

so how can i create those RatedMovies and Ratings lists in SQLite database in android (i already created the database) and how can i add items or read the items from it?
Here is the code used for DataBaseHelper and how i added the information for each user:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DataBaseHelper";
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
        super(context,name,factory,version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USER(EMAIL TEXT PRIMARY KEY,Password TEXT,NAME TEXT,PHONE LONG,GENDER TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {


    }
    public boolean insertUser (User user){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("EMAIL",user.getEmail());
        contentValues.put("Password",user.getPassword());
        contentValues.put("NAME",user.getName());
        contentValues.put("PHONE",user.getPhone());
        contentValues.put("GENDER",user.getGender());
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.insert("USER",null,contentValues);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getAllUsers() {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER ORDER BY EMAIL ASC", null); //set it to sort by name ascending
    }
    public void updateName(String newName, String email, String oldName,String newPassword,String oldPassword){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE USER" + " SET " + "NAME" +
                " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + "EMAIL" + " = '" + email + "'" +
                " AND " + "NAME" + " = '" + oldName + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName);
        db.execSQL(query);
        String query2 = "UPDATE USER" + " SET " + "Password" +
                " = '" + newPassword + "' WHERE " + "EMAIL" + " = '" + email + "'" +
                " AND " + "Password" + " = '" + oldPassword + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query2);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newPassword);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

Comment: Storing multiple values in a column in a relational database is almost always a sign of a poor database design. Consider normalizing the table to first normal form. This will save you a lot of time and trouble trying to work with the data.

Comment: so i guess i understood what you said @HoneboyWilson. so now instead, i want to build a database for each movie and in them i will add users with their ratings, but this creates the issue that i will have to search all movies to know what movies did each person rate. also i found out that there should also be comments on those movies and i must show them, so what is the best database approach for this?

Comment: You need to determine what entities the project requires and create a table for each entity. Then you need to determine the relationships between the entities and store those relationships in the database. For example, one user can rate many movies and a movie can be rated by many users. That's a many-to-many relationship and you will need a linking table to store that information. If these concepts aren't obvious to you then you might consider taking a database design course.

Comment: thank you for your suggesstions, in fact i still know nothing about database and i'm hopefully having its' course next semester, but i took android lab and it had some light usage for database, however, the project they gave us had some more database than in the course itself so i'm having troubles with that